# How to avoid from storing date objects in array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, datetime-format

Consider below code:

```
dates = ["20th OCT 1232", "6th JUN 2019", "23th AUG 2017", "9th JAN 2015"]

def reformateDate(dates)
    ans = []
    dates.length.times do |i|
        ans << (DateTime.parse(dates[i], '%d %b %Y').to_date)
    end
    ans
end
```

This function return array in below format:

```
[#<Date: 1232-10-20 ((2171339j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2019-06-06 ((2458641j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2017-08-23 ((2457989j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Date: 2015-01-09 ((2457032j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

But i want it to return array in this format:

```
["1232-10-20","2019-06-06","2017-08-23","2015-01-09"]
```

So how can i do this?

Comment: https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strptime/class

Comment: This will also create a date object and store it like a object in array.

Comment: how are you storing these values? a database?  why do you prefer strings over date objects?

Comment: but they are date objects. if you just want the strings then maybe to_string after you set the format

Comment: Where did `"23th"` come from? One would expect it to be `"23rd"`. I assume the array may also contain `"1th"`, `"2th"` `"3th"`, `"21th"` and `"22th"`. Weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dates.map { |e| Date.parse(e).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }
#=> ["1232-10-20", "2019-06-06", "2017-08-23", "2015-01-09"]
```

Change the template `'%Y-%m-%d'` according to your needs, see this for reference: [Date#strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime).

---

Picking up the wise suggestion from Cary Swoveland.

Instead of `Date.parse(e)` you can use `Date.strptime(e, '%dth %b %Y')`, which works more or less the reverse of strftime. See [Date#strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime). It follows a template (`'%dth %b %Y'`) to interpret the original string as a date. Adding `th` to the template after `%d` (day), it converts properly the current format to a date object:

```
Date.strptime("20th OCT 1232", '%dth %b %Y') #=> #<Date: 1232-10-20 ((2171339j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

But, what if the date is `'1st OCT 2018'` or `'23rd OCT 2018'`? The template does not match, because it expects to find `th` and not `st` or `rd`.

To be *ordinal suffix agnostic*, comes in hand the method [String#sub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-sub):

```
"20th OCT 1232".sub(/(?<=\d)\p{Alpha}+/, '') #=> "20 OCT 1232"
```

So, mixing all together, the best solution to be safe should be:

```
dates.map { |e| Date.strptime(e.sub(/(?<=\d)\p{Alpha}+/, ''), '%d %b %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }
```

Comment: To be safer I suggest using `Date#strptime` instead of `parse`. Also, it would prudent to anticipate `"23th"` being corrected to `"23rd"`or `"23"` in future, so that would be `dates.map { |s| Date.strptime(s.sub(/(?<=\d)\p{Alpha}+/, ''),  '%d %b %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }`. `Date.parse('junebug') #=> #<Date: 2018-06-01 ((2458271j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>` exemplifies my distaste for `parse`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, wise as usual. Picked up. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're actually storing Date objects when you write:

`ans << (DateTime.parse(dates[i], '%d %b %Y').to_date)`

There's a couple of problems with this: First, the parenthesis don't do anything, so you can remove them. Second, what you're doing is parsing a string into a DateTime object, and then converting it into a Date object. Not really sure why you would do that, but I believe it's a mistake. If you want to convert this to a string by temporally using DateTime objects, consider using `strftime`, which will take the DateTime object and turn it into a string with a specific format. It would look like this:

`ans << DateTime.parse(dates[i], '%d %b %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
require 'date'

def reformat_date(dates)
  dates.map { |date| Date.parse(date).to_s }
end

dates = ["20th OCT 1232", "6th JUN 2019", "23th AUG 2017", "9th JAN 2015"]
reformat_date(dates)
#=> ["1232-10-20", "2019-06-06", "2017-08-23", "2015-01-09"]
```

Comment: `Date#parse` is the beast :) `Date.parse("20 O 20").to_s #⇒ "2018-11-20"`.